# Haven't access to Angular Material in feature module

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have not access to Angular Material Component in my feature module.

Description:

I've three modules:
1) feature module, let's call it 'xModule'
2) my own module which imports and exports all angular material components which I use,
3) app.module which imports upper two modules.

Situation:

Material component isn't available in component which is register in xModule.
Same material component is available in component registered in app.module (app.component).

Target behaviour:

All material components should be available in all features modules.

I don't understand this behaviour because i think that xModule belongs to app.module which is global/main module, so if app.module import angular material module, all material components should be available in whole application. Please explain me it.

What is the best practice to allow feature modules to use angular material components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either import your material modules into your root module (normally the app-module), or create a [shared module](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) and import them there.

Comment: Did you read my text? I imported material module to app.module.

Comment: Fredrik is right. You have to import your material module in the module where you add the declarations for the component. This is because imports just work in one direction. So if import material module and feature module in app module - material module wouldn't get imported into feature module. We added a shared module in our application which gets imported in every feature module. Shared module imports/exports all UI relevant (material, pipes, directives ...) stuff.